# Why does my program not run outside the source folder?

Tags: path, dependencies, ubuntu-12.04, lazarus

I'm writing a program using Lazarus + Ubuntu 12.04.

I compile the program and run the binary. It works, There are also reports created using LazReports and they all work fine.

But the moment I copy the binary to another folder like /usr/local/bin, it works **without** the reports. When I try to view a report, I see a warning like this:

> [WARNING] SetAlphaBlend called without handle for
>   frProgressForm(TfrProgressForm)

But the program continues... I think this is to do with LazReport needing some sort of file in the current location but I cannot make out what it is.

Any idea on how I can get this working?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Voila!

The solution was to copy the .lrf (report) file to the folder that held the binary of my program.